# How to tell MapStruct "not" to use the Lombok Builder?

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have the following classes and mapper to map them.
How can I configure Mapstruct to "not" use the Lombok builder? (without removing the @Builder annotation)?
When using the latest version of Lombok and mapstruct, mapstruct will automatically use the Builder when the @Builder annotation is used. I can not find a way to disable that, as I need the Instance in an @AfterMapping method as the builder doesn't expose all required methods (@SuperBuilder is not allowed in this use case)

```
@Entity(name = "user_details")
@Data
@Builder
public class User extends AuditableEntityBase {

    @Version
    @NotNull
    private Integer version;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    private Address address; // Just another Class containing another class that is mapped as well.

}

@Value
@Builder
public class UserDto extends AuditableEntityBaseDto {

    @NotNull
    private Integer version;

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    private String email;


    @NotNull
    private AddressDto address;
}


@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
class UserRestMapper {
    public abstract UserDto map(User obj);

}

    @AfterMapping
    public void decorate(User source, @MappingTarget AuditableEntityBase target) {
// Method is never called.
// Method is called in case  the second argument is: "@MappingTarget UserDto.UserDtoBuilder target"
    }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to disable using builders you can do so by adding `@Builder(disableBuilder = true)` to your `@Mapper`.

e.g.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", builder = @Builder(disableBuilder = true))
class UserRestMapper {
    public abstract UserDto map(User obj);

}
```

**Note** `@Builder` is from the `org.mapstruct` package

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for :-) .. Stupid that I didn't notice that annotatie attribute.

Comment: Is it also possible to disable it per mapping method?

Answer (score 0):

No idea about disabling it, but why not do it like this?

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
abstract class UserRestMapper {
    public abstract UserDto map(User obj);
    
    public UserDto decoratedMap(User obj) {
        UserDto mapped = map(obj);
        // your after mapping logic
        return mapped;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's too restricted. Sorry, I left out nested objects in the User that need to call the same @AfterMapping method... I have changed my minimal use case (it was a bit too minimal)